# IP address is not reachable or is invalid

Tags: networking, jenkins

I am facing a strange issue these days. I have a list of IP addresses which I want to connect to during the deployment using Jenkins. Now what is happening is, if I am deploying at one IP address (remote machine but in same location) in my local location server, I can successfully do that. But If I am trying to deploy to an IP address (remote machine in other country/region) It is throwing the error, saying

```
Error : Ip address XYZ is not reachable or is invalid.
```

***Please be notified that I am able to get the response from the machine when I ping it using:***

```
ping XYZ
```

But while trying to deploy on it using Jenkins, I am not.
Please let me know if there's any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough data points but you can look for these things
 1. IP address, Check if all three machines are in same n/w (Jenkins Server, target and your machine)
    You can check it with IP address of each machine
 2. check Gateway set for Jenkins server
 3. Best way if feasible is to ssh / rdp to your Jenkins server and try running your command manually that will give you

Comment: Hi, My local machine is only my Jenkins server(I installed jenkins in my local machine) now I am able to deploy to servers which are in India ESX but not on the servers which are in Denver ESX. there are 100's of server there so point 3 I think will not be feasible.

Comment: okay, you can try with one of machine just to check connectivity and execution of commands.

also just to clarify your ping command is working for vm / servers on Denver ESXi.
if Yes, it's probably issue with firewall blocking you ports 
if No then we are back to #2 .. i.e. check gateway and ensure there is route from your server to Machines in Denver

Answer (score 0):

Local machine get loopback address(127.0.0.1), so it will be reachable or any local machine having IP address with same subnet mask thats called LAN.

When you are reaching out to remote machine, either it should be public IP address(visible to everyone in the world) or you must have connect to that Area-Network via VPN, this is called tunnelling to remote over the WAN (wide area network). Their(remote location) again, you will notice that all the IP address have same subnet mask as you have on the local machine.

So their could be be IP address duplication case in VPN scenario, where you are bale to ping but not able to reach. This is because, IP address is assigned to other machine but not you yours and ping responses are coming from that other machine. That means your machine is in failed to resolve ARP and in dormant state.